# Elastic potential of a balloon and pressure equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, gas

There are two different pressures acting on the surface of a balloon, the external one is clearly weaker than the internal one, so there must be a force that create equilibrium and avoid the balloon to break.

Now, this force is determined by the elastic potential *Ue* of the surface (measured in J).

How is this force related to the two different pressures?

I am aware of [Laplace equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_pressure), but it includes a surface tension (measured in N/m) that I really don't know how to compute starting from the value of *Ue* expressed in Joule.

Thank you!

Comment: what makes you think that the internal pressure is larger than the atmospheric pressure of the air surrounding the ballon?

Comment: Well I'm talking about one of those balloons that you find at parties. The pressure of the air that you inflate inside is greater than the pressure outside, otherwise you would not have tension on the surface and air wouldn't desperately try to go outside.

Comment: The difference in pressure corresponds to the increase in strain energy of the balloon material per unit increase in balloon volume.